# Error using nested masterpages while posting forms

Tags: asp.net

After some tough error research I've found the reason of a problem of mine I don't understand. I have a page with form controls that resides inside a nested masterpage. Whenever I try to run the form I run into this error:

```
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ]
```

If I choose to run the form as a clean page without any reference to the masterpage it posts perfect.

I have tried the following solutions with no luck:

- I've added a validationKey in the web.config,
- I've set the enableEventValidation="true", enableViewState="true" and left the enableViewStateMac="true" as stated in the MSDN documentation,
- I've added a viewStateEncryptionMode="true",
- I've also added a maxPageStateFieldLength="400" in the web.config.

Do you guys have an explanation to why this error occurs and some advice on how to solve it?

Comment: Yep, I have a parent master (Site.master) which contains a child master (ContentPage.master) that pages are loaded into. The reason for this is that the start page has a different layout than the rest of the site which I want to use nested masterpages for...

Comment: Actually you could nest masterpages as shown at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x2b3ktt7(v=vs.100).aspx). :)

Comment: @DariusVaughan-Scott yes you can nest as many master pages as you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to circumvent this problem without solving it. As I mentioned in my question I believe this problem is related to my use of nested master pages. I managed to bypass it in this fashion.

First I created a plain page without references to any master page holding the input forms and the submit method. I then added a div to a second page working as a content holder to the sub master page onto which I load the form page using JavaScript and the jQuery UI library 'modal'.

This is a snippet:

**Content holding page**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.edit-post').removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
        var linkid = $(this).attr('rel');

        $('#edit-post').load('<%=Utilities.Helpers.ResolveUrl("~/article.aspx?id=' + linkid + '")%>').dialog({
            closeOnEscape: false,
            closeText: 'close',
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 700
        });
    });
});
<div id="edit-post"></div>
```

**article.aspx**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Edit your post</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="EditPostForm" runat="server">
        The inputs...
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not a solution to the real problem but it eradicates the effects of the problem using quite another method then initially intended by eliminating the need of inheriting the viewstate of any master page. What do you guys think of this?

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by a number of reasons and it could be hard to get to the root of the problem in such a small space as StackOverflow. But, if you start from knowing the fact that this error is thrown because the viewstate is corrupted, then you should be able to investigate your environment and find out what is causing to get viewstate corrupted...you can confirm this by turning off viewstate and check if the error still happens. A couple of reasons why this errors could happen

1. You are using IIS dynamic compression and something is going wrong with the configuration
2. The viewstate is massive...inspect the page's footprint and check the size of the viewstate field, some firewalls and/or proxies truncate viewstate if it exceeds a specific size...you can easily get around this by splitting viewstate into multiple hidden fields..check the [`MaxPageStateFieldLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maxpagestatefieldlength(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation

Comment: Okay, so the masterpages automatically adds data to the viewstate? Does each masterpage add this information?

Comment: @KristoferGisslén yes, anything that inherits from the `System.Web.UI.Control` can generate viewstate, a master page will generate viewstate from everything it finds in its `Controls` property hierarchy if viewstate is enabled...remember that control state cannot be turned off and always generate viewstate as well. Both the `MasterPage` class and the `Page` class inherit from the `Control` class...

Comment: Ouch. That explains a whole lot. :) I will try to split the wiewstate in order to find the solution. Is there a way to work around this problem so that I can nest the page inside the masterpage in a simple way?

Comment: @KristoferGisslén sorry, I didn't understand your question. There's only one way to nest master pages which is through the `MasterPageFile` of the `Master` directive. Also, you shouldn't need to worry about pages and master pages viewstate because they're implementation doesn't generate viewstate directly...it is its child controls that can add up to the viewstate field. Try converting any server control that you don't need to reference in code-behind to a plain native html element, turning viewstate off for controls that don't need viewstate, etc. and see what happens